# NoMethodError (undefined method `product_url'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following error when debugging my first project on rails:

NoMethodError (undefined method `product_url' for #
Did you mean?  products_url):

app/controllers/products_controller.rb:13:in `create'

---

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end 

  def new
  end

  def create
      @product = Product.new(product_params)
      @product.save
      redirect_to @product
  end

  private
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:title, :price, :count)
    end
end
```

----------config/routes.rb------

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  resource :products
  root 'welcome#index'

end

----------rake routes----------

```
               Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
        welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)                                                                 welcome#index
         new_products GET    /products/new(.:format)                                                                  products#new
        edit_products GET    /products/edit(.:format)                                                                 products#edit
             products GET    /products(.:format)                                                                      products#show
                      PATCH  /products(.:format)                                                                      products#update
                      PUT    /products(.:format)                                                                      products#update
                      DELETE /products(.:format)                                                                      products#destroy
                      POST   /products(.:format)
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you edited your question (using the `edit` link just below the tags) to include (1) the relevant parts of `config/routes.rb` and (2) the console output of `rake routes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialise @product. It can be done like:

```
before_action :set_document, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def set_document
  @document = Document.find(params[:id])
end
```

You can scaffold the Controller with

```
rails g scaffold_controller Document
```

to see exactly how rails is generating classes for a model.

In your ***routes.rb*** it should be

```
resources: products
```

Comment: thanks, I should use  "resources" not  "resource" in routes.rb